# Proof that an AR(p) process is stationary IFF the roots of the characteristic equation lie outside the unit circle?

Tags: statistics, time-series, stationary-processes

I was wondering whether anyone could shed light on an approach, schema or a link to a proof. Finding difficulty in finding one.

Cheers